# Vim: yank Regex match to +clipboard

Tags: regex, vim, clipboard

Example `:%y+` yanks to external +clipboard. Now I want results by regexes such as `^\S\+` to the external +clipboard. How?

**Trial 1. [Fail]** `:g@^\S\+@y+`

**Trial 2. [Fail]** `:^\S\+y+`

Answer (score 8):

Have a look here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_the_search_results_into_clipboard, the section 'Copying lines containing search hits'.

This worked for me (clear register `a`, yank `pattern` results into it, copy over into clipboard):

```
qaq
:g/pattern/y A
:let @+ = @a
```

When I tried `:g/pattern/y+` it only copied the first line.

That section on the link also gives a function you can write to copy all lines, but it still looks like a 2-step process (do `/pattern` and then call the function): but you could probably write your own macro/shortcut to do both in sequence.

Comment: this direct answer copies whole lines where regex is contained. But in the link given above, there's a script named CopyMatches copies only the matched parts.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can find some inspiration in the following:

```
:saveas %.tmp
```

to start working on a copy

```
:v//d
:exec '%s/^.\{-\}\(' . @/ . '\).*$/\1/g'
```

So for example doing a search `/word\d` on the following text:

> Tincidunt. Proin **sagittis2**. Curabitur auctor metus non mauris. Nunc condimentum
>   nisl non augue. Donec leo urna, dignissim vitae, porttitor ut, iaculis sit
>   amet, sem.
>
> Class aptent taciti **sociosqu3** ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
>   inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque augue metus, hendrerit sit
>   amet, commodo vel, scelerisque ut, ante. Praesent euismod euismod risus. Mauris
>   ut metus sit amet mi cursus commodo. Morbi congue mauris ac sapien. Donec
>   justo. Sed congue nunc vel **mauris0**. Pellentesque vehicula orci id libero. In hac
>   habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla sollicitudin, **purus1** id elementum dictum, dolor
>   augue hendrerit ante, vel semper metus enim et dolor. Pellentesque **molestie9**.

will highlight the words as shown. Doing

```
:v//d|exec '%s/^.\{-\}\(' . @/ . '\).*$/\1/g'
```

results in the following buffer:

```
sagittis2
sociosqu3
mauris0
purus1
molestie9
```

Comment: The OP should bear in mind that you only get one match per line with this. If you want multiple matches per line try `:%s/MYREGEXP/\r&\r/g | v//d`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. First define a function for saving your
matched regexps into a list (:help List).

```
:fun Add(list, item)
:   call add(a:list, a:item)
:   return a:item
:endfun
```

Note that it also returns the added item. This isn't necessary,
but what you return here becomes the replacement text in the
:substitute that follows below.

Next, create an empty list.

```
:let list=[]
```

Then run your regexp.

```
:%s/^\S\+/\=Add(list, submatch(0))/
```

Note that the replacement begins with \= (see :help
sub-replace-special). The result is that we replace the match expression
with itself, but at the same time capture the result in list.

The submatch() function returns matched parts of the :substitute
command. submatch(0) returns the entire match.

Note that as a side effect the buffer is marked as having been changed.
If you saved the buffer before you executed the substitution then you
can fix this by simply hitting u for undo, or appending '| u' to your
command. (If you are going to undo the operation then it doesn't matter
what we return from our Add function.)

You can view your matches with

```
:echo list
```

or you can append them to your buffer with

```
:$put=list
```

I hope this helps. It's straightforward once you know how, but there's
quite a lot to digest there.

Oh, I nearly forgot! You can add your matches to the clipboard with

```
:let @+ = join(list, '^@')
```

Then your matches will be in the clipboard, each on a separate line.

^@ represents a NUL character, and is generated with <C-V><C-J>, meaning
press control-V, followed by control-J. (Why you have to use ^@ here is
a whole topic in itself.)

Comment: Good answer. I think you can do without the list by appending to @+ directly. I suspect your answer will perform better in the general case, though

Comment: Yes that would work too, thanks. The OP might prefer that, though storing the words in a list gives you options too.

Comment: you can also store the clipboard in a list afterwards: `let list=[] // let list = split(@+, '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

append all search result to `reg X`(uppercase) separated by newline:

```
:g/^/call setreg('X', matchstr(getline('.'), '^\S\+') . "\n")
```

to clear `reg x`:

```
qxq
```